# SO_REUSEPORT Error in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I get the following two errors when i try to run my program on the AVD:

> Emulator: E0630 09:34:36.670338059 9681
> socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT:
> {"created":"@1593498876.670313972","description":"SO_REUSEPORT
> unavailable on compiling
> system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
>
> Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found

I use ubuntu 16.04 on an Hp probook 4540s

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessfully trying all my tricks, i reinstalled android studio (making sure to install it at no other place than the "/opt" directory) but the same problem still came up, however, the newest android studio at the time (4.0) with the newest gradle (4.0) came with a new feature which helped me out.

After creating a new project, instead of using the **Build/play** button to build the app for the first time, i used a button in the "What's new " section called **Build Analyzer** and after some minutes, i got the app successfully running in the emulator!

Although the app was running but the error kept been displayed on the screen until after running the app for a number of times.

the Feature is in the "What's new " (Assistant) section and can be reached by clicking: **help>what's New in Android Studio** scroll down the "What's new" pop up window until you see the "Build Analyzer" button then click it and wait for background processes to finish.